# How to detect if mediacontroller is visible or not?

Tags: android, android-videoview, mediacontroller

I made an Android app in Android Studio. The app has a VideoView.

I have a textview that contains the title of the video currently playing.

I want to show the textview only when the mediacontroller of the video is visible.

How can I achieve that ?

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
if(mediacontroller.isShowing())
     txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
else
     txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anyone help me please ? :(

Answer (score 0):

Try: `mediaController.isShown()` instead of `mediaController.isShowing()`

Comment: It would be better if you could also describe what is the source of the problem and why this solution should work (perhaps some links to the documentation?).

Comment: where are you getting this method from?

Comment: IsShown () is a method from View which MediaController indirectly extends. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Answer (score 0):

hi I read your question , you need particular call back when videoController get visible and get hide so you can try below code !

```
 yourVideController.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View v) {
          Textview.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE);
      }

      @Override
      public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View v) {
         Textview.setVisiblity(View.GONE);
      }
  });
```

Or in Kotlin:

```
mediaController.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(object : View.OnAttachStateChangeListener {
                override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(p0: View?) {

                }

                override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(p0: View?) {
                    
                }

            })
```

Good luck !